# How To Make A Frame That Can Be Resized in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame

I am using Tkinter and have a frame which needs to be be rezised, is this possible to do without changing the way the class or the grid manager works (inheriting Frame methods and using a frame as my window)? I tried looking at other Stack Overflow Q&A's but can't quite understand them because each question has other pieces of code which are interfering with the general question.

The Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame): # Inherits Frame methods

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='LightBlue') # Initializes the frame

        self.master = master # Creates master

        self.init_window()  # Method to grid

        self.master.mainloop() # Runs window

    def init_window(self):

        self.grid()


root = Tk()  # Creates a master
app = Window(root) # Initializes app using root as master
```

Could someone please help me with this?

EDIT:

Why does Novel's answer work as opposed to...

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame): # Inherits Frame methods

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='LightBlue') # Initializes the frame

        self.master = master # Creates master

        self.init_window()  # Method to grid

        self.master.mainloop() # Runs window

    def init_window(self):

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root = Tk()  # Creates a master
app = Window(root) # Initializes app using root as master
```

Could someone please explain this too?

Comment: `grid` has many documented options. Have you tried using them to see what they do?

Comment: Could you leave a link to a few, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use columnconfigure and rowconfigure to set the grid columns and rows to expand with the window. Also:

- don't use wildcard imports
- use the `sticky` argument to keep a widget sized to the grid cell
- don't layout a Frame inside the same frame. IOW don't use `self.grid()`, always initialize and use `instance.grid()` on the outside.
- be sure to pass the kwargs anytime you subclass a tkinter widget
- check out more beginner oriented forums, like learnpython.reddit.com

All that together:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame): # Inherits Frame methods
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='LightBlue', **kwargs) # Initializes the frame

root = tk.Tk()  # Creates a master
root.geometry('200x200') # set initial size
app = Window(root) # Initializes app using root as master
app.grid(sticky='nsew') # set this widget to keep the size of the grid cell
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # Set the first column to expand with the window
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # Set the first row to expand with the window
root.mainloop() # Runs window
```

You could also use `pack` to do the same thing with less code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame): # Inherits Frame methods
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='LightBlue', **kwargs) # Initializes the frame

root = tk.Tk()  # Creates a master
root.geometry('200x200') # set initial size
app = Window(root) # Initializes app using root as master
app.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True) # set this widget to fill all available space
root.mainloop() # Runs window
```

Re your edit:

You need to set rowconfigure on the Widget's *master*, not the Widget itself. The master decides how much space the Widget gets. So you could use self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) if you wanted, but the structure I showed is much better for reading code. Code gets confusing if you modify the master from within a child Widget.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really set up to teach beginner level code. Go to a different forum where comments can contain code.

Comment: Look, I redid the question... Please look.